# the event log file is full

Tags: c#, asp.net, datasource, event-log

the event log file is full.

when i connect my datasource im getting this error. i cannot able to connect my datasource. how to do this.how to solve this..pls help

Comment: possible duplicate of [The Event Log File is full](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1300216/the-event-log-file-is-full)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You will need to clear the event log manually.

Go to the event viewer on the machine and clear the log. Think about setting the log to overwrite when it fills up, or to clear out any messages that are older than a suitable threshold.

Comment: @Ranjana - open the event viewer on the affected machine, right click the log in question - Clear all events is the option you need.

Answer (score 1):

Type the `eventvwr` in the run , then right click on application and then `clear all events`